# How to plot assortativity with R?

Tags: r, igraph, sna

I found the figure below in literature about assortativity (for networks). I would like to plot my network in a similar way with R & `igraph`. 
Every point on the graph corresponds to a network edge. In my case x axis should represent the source node's degree, y axis the target node's degree. I am a beginner in R and therefore would very much appreciate if someone could help me to plot this. 
[image]

I now used the code from Vincent Zoonekynd and got the figure below. However I think that it still doesn't show exactly the right thing. The nodes on the axis should be ranked by their degree. When I look at the plot, I see some nodes with high degree which are plased around axis mark 42, 100 or 175. This makes not much sense. Is there something wrong with the rank process here?

```
A <- get.adjacency(USAN_g_num)            
image(A,  ylim=c(0,627))             
i <- rank( degree(USAN_g_num), na.last=NA, ties.method="first" )
image(A[i,i], ylim=c(0,627))
```

(I added an ylim to the code so that both, low-low degrees and high-high degrees are plottet in the same corner bottom-left and upper-right)
But it is correct that my plot should look different from the one I showed above, since my data is disassortative. 
[image]

Comment: Have you looked at `?igraph.plot`?  Please try to do some research on your own and share what you've tried and how it didn't work before posting here.

Comment: @Justin: Well ?igraph.plot does not actually work with my version but I checked the plot commands of igraph anyway. Didn't find a command that creates the plot I need. What thought is that I first need a matrix of the corresponding source and target node's degrees. After that I can try to plot it with points (as shown above) or with some kind of correlation matrix plot. But I have difficulties to bring my thoughts into R code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the adjacency matrix of a graph,
with the nodes sorted by degree.

```
# Sample data
library(igraph)
library(Matrix)
g <- erdos.renyi.game(10, p=1/2) + erdos.renyi.game(10, p=1/2)

# Plot the adjacency matrix
A <- get.adjacency(g)
image(A)

# In this example, sorting the nodes by degree is not a good idea
i <- order( degree(g) )
image(A[i,i])
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried it with your code and it pretty much worked. However I think something with the rank process went wrong. I updated my initial post above. If you could take a look that would be perfect. Thx again.

Comment: Oh perfect thx. I also tried with `sort`but your are right, `order`is the correct way to go.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this.`image()` does not accept the adjacency matrix(?)

Comment: @jO.: get.adjacency now returns a sparse matrix: you need to explicitly load the Matrix package.